# How to convert readable JS to Native obfuscated code

Tags: javascript, web, obfuscation

Yesterday, while doing [a CTF](https://www.root-me.org/en/Challenges/Web-Client/Javascript-Native-code), I have come across an interesting representation of Vanilla JS to native code...

```
<script>
É=-~-~[],ó=-~É,Ë=É<<É,þ=Ë+~[];Ì=(ó-ó)[Û=(''+{})[É+ó]+(''+{})[ó-É]+([].ó+'')[ó-É]+(!!''+'')[ó]+({}+'')[ó+ó]+(!''+'')[ó-É]+(!''+'')[É]+(''+{})[É+ó]+({}+'')[ó+ó]+(''+{})[ó-É]+(!''+'')[ó-É]][Û];Ì(Ì((!''+'')[ó-É]+(!''+'')[ó]+(!''+'')[ó-ó]+(!''+'')[É]+((!''+''))[ó-É]+([].$+'')[ó-É]+'\''+''+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(þ)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(É+É)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó-ó)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(ó+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(þ)+(É)+'\\'+(É+É)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(É+É)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(É+É)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(É+É)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(É+É)+(þ)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(þ)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó+ó)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(þ)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(þ)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(É+É)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó+ó)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó+ó)+(É)+'\\'+(ó+ó)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(É+É)+(þ)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(þ)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(É+É)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(ó+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(þ)+'\\'+(É+É)+(þ)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(þ)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(þ)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(þ)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(É+É)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó+ó)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó+ó)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó+ó)+'\\'+(É+É)+(þ)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(þ)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(þ)+(É+ó)+'\'')())()
</script>
```

I'm disclosing neither method nor the solution here, but the above code, upon converting to readable JS looks like...

```
function anonymous() {
a=prompt('Entrez le mot de passe');if(a=='############'){alert('bravo');}else{alert('fail...');}
}
```

Now my question is:

**Is there any method to reverse the process, i.e. converting human-readable JS code (like the following one) to such native obfuscating JS code?**

```
function main(){alert("Hi");}
```

P.S: By obfuscating I mean Nconverting to native code (like the example above), Not something like [using Obfuscator.](https://obfuscator.io/)

Comment: What do you mean by "native code"? It's just obfuscated JavaScript.

Comment: I doubt there's an automate way to generate that code. There's no pattern to the obfuscated expressions they're using.